# In the SE landingpage markup an anchor tag is nested in an anchor tag and alt attribute is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, stackexchange.com, rendering

The markup on the new and improved [StackExchange.com landing page](https://stackexchange.com/) contains html markup that isn't allowed according the specification.

Please note that the functionality of the page is **NOT AFFECTED** in anyway.

```
<div class="question-container">
    <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173268/mathematicians-who-made-important-contributions-outside-their-own-field">
            <div class="hot-question-site-icon">
                <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173268/mathematicians-who-made-important-contributions-outside-their-own-field" title="view this question on mathoverflow.net"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathoverflow/img/icon-48.png" /></a>
            </div>
    </a>
```

The W3C Validator claims:

> Error: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

Inside the *hero-box* the all the `img` tags are missing an alt-atrribute

```
      <div class="column">
            <img src="/content/img/hero/bubble.png" />
            <div class="blurb">
                <em>Expert communities.</em><br />
                Each of our <span class="old">125</span> 
                communities is built by people passionate about a focused topic.
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Error: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions.

Even IE11 barks about it!

When you are going to touch that page, can you fix those two minor bugs as well?

Comment: +1 for reporting, but on the other hand, it would be more important for SE to improve the pre-commit QA for such clear cases. That procedural issue is more severe than one bug here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pushing out some changes that fix all of the above and which validate on the w3 validator.

Thanks for letting us know.